# SQL oracle where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSONNE
WHERE PERSONNE.NO_PERSONNE = GENEALOGIE.NO_PERSONNE
  AND GENEALOGIE.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Baptême'
  AND GENEALOGIE.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN != 'Ste-Lubie'
  AND GENEALOGIE.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Mariage'
  AND GENEALOGIE.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie';
```

I would love to do something like that.

select where the person has been married in Ste-Lubie but not 'Baptême' in Ste-Lubie.

Comment: `GENEALOGIE.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Baptême' AND GENEALOGIE.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Mariage'`??? What are you trying to achieve actually? Could you please show us some sample data in the table and the required output?

Comment: are there values of `TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN` other than 'Baptême' and 'Mariage'?

Comment: Show your table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSONNE
  JOIN GENEALOGIE ON PERSONNE.NO_PERSONNE = GENEALOGIE.NO_PERSONNE
  LEFT JOIN GENEALOGIE GEN_NOT ON (PERSONNE.NO_PERSONNE = GENEALOGIE.NO_PERSONNE AND  GENEALOGIE.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Baptême' AND GENEALOGIE.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie')
WHERE 
  GENEALOGIE.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Mariage'
  AND GENEALOGIE.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie'
  AND GEN_NOT.NO_PERSONNE IS NULL
```

Some modifications, should work I guess...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PERSONNE P,GENEALOGIE G
WHERE P.NO_PERSONNE = G.NO_PERSONNE
  AND G.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Mariage'
  AND G.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie'
  AND NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 'X' FROM GENEALOGIE G1
    WHERE P.NO_PERSONNE = G1.NO_PERSONNE
      AND G1.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Baptême'
      AND G1.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie')
```

OR

```
SELECT P.*
FROM PERSONNE P
WHERE P.NO_PERSONNE IN
  (SELECT NO_PERSONNE FROM GENEALOGIE G1
     WHERE G1.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Mariage'
       AND G1.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie' 
   MINUS
   SELECT NO_PERSONNE FROM GENEALOGIE G1
     WHERE G1.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Baptême'
       AND G1.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.*
FROM PERSONNE T1
INNER JOIN GENEALOGIE T2
ON T1.NO_PERSONNE = T2.NO_PERSONNE
WHERE T2.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Baptême'
AND T2.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN != 'Ste-Lubie'
AND T2.TYPE_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Mariage'
AND T2.LIEU_EVENEMENT_GEN = 'Ste-Lubie';
```